# How to neglect/drop a c# "out" variable?

Tags: c#

Say I have been provided a function that looks something like this:

```
int doSomething(int parameter, out someBigMemoryClass uselessOutput) {...}
```

I want to use this function but I don't need the `uselessOutput` variable at all. How can I get the function to work without using the `uselessOutput`, preferably without allocating any new memory?

Comment: If you can't modify this method there's nothing you can do because the method initializes it. If you don't use it the garbage collector will reclaim this memory when needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply put - you can't. Either pass a variable and ignore the `out` afterwards (**if** the memory hit from allocating the `out` parameter is tiny, i.e., not a big memory class) or edit the code for the function yourself.

One way I thought of just now actually is to wrap the function too, if its annoying having to pass an ignored `out` variable all the time. It doesn't get rid of the `out` for the original function, but it provides us a way to call the function without caring about the `out` variable at all.

```
class OutExample
{
    static void Method(out int i)
    {
        i = 44;
    }
    static void MethodWrapper() 
    {
        int i = 0;
        Method(out i);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int value;
        Method(out value);
        // value is now 44

        MethodWrapper();
        // No value needed to be passed - function is wrapped. Method is still called within MethodWrapper, however.
    }
}
```

This, however, doesn't solve your big memory class issue, should you call this a lot of times. For that, you would need to rewrite the function. Calling it within the wrapper function would still require the same memory allocation unfortunately.

Comment: The memory hit won't be so negligible if the method do some intensive stuff to give a value to that unused parameter.

Comment: @Sehnsucht I'm going to assume that isn't the case, as it usually isn't. The question doesn't specify that as a problem, however if it is a better solution would be needed. stakx has provided a solution below that may help avoid that problem. This avoids the `out` parameter rather neatly, though.

Comment: @Sehnsucht Also, wouldn't that performance hit always be there if intensive operations are performed on the parameter anyway? You'd need to remove the code that performs the intensive function, regardless of how the method was wrapper. That would always require the function to be rewritten, unless I'm overseeing something

Comment: the problem with an out parameter is we can give it null (typed appropriately) if we want ; it's the method which has the role to assign it a value ; so if it's as noted by the OP some big memory class ; chances are it will be allocated inside the offended method regardless of what we gave it

Comment: Well noted! I'll have a think... EDIT: The thoughts have been had, and I can't think of a way without editting the method itself. I'll update my answer to reflect the big memory class stuff

Comment: Thanks for the valuable thoughts, I've actually used an another way to achieve my bigger goal but this smaller problem's solutions might come in handy sooner or later and I really love stakx's answer. It seems that `out` doesn't copy anything and writes on top of that variable you provide, so the memory problem can't really be fixed any more without access to the original function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to simply omit an `out` parameter, but you can make your life a little more comfortable by wrapping your method in an extension method that doesn't have the `out` parameter:

```
// let's assume the method in question is defined on type `Foo`:
static class FooExtensions
{
    public static int doSomething(this Foo foo, int parameter)
    {
        someBigMemoryClass _;
        return foo.doSomething(parameter, out _);
    }
}
```

Then call that extension method instead of the actual instance method:

```
Foo foo = …;
int result = foo.doSomething(42);
```

(And whenever you *do* want to specify the `out` parameter, you still can, because the original method is still there.)

Of course the original method will still produce the unneeded `someBigMemoryClass` object, which might be a (hopefully short-lived) waste of resources. Better to change the original method directly, if that is an option.